# Java script code for pressing alt+f4 key

Tags: javascript

I need a java script code for a button click that press alt+f4 key of keyboard.
So I achieve the same functionality as pressing alt+F4.

So please suggest me how I can do that.

Comment: What does Alt+F4 do?

Comment: I just tried it. It closed my browser :(

Comment: Alt-f4 usually closes the current window/app.

Comment: close the current window

Comment: do you want to close the current window?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)...

Comment: I agree with @Passerby why do you need to close a users window? If he wanted to do that he can close it by clicking the "x" button.

Answer (score 0):

That key event is (on most OSs I guess) processed by the OS before it's even sent to the browser, so capturing it inside a browser wont help.

What u want is to replicate the **window/tab** ***close*** event and AFAIK the only way in Javascript to detect that kind of stuffs are `onunload` & `onbeforeunload` events.

Unfortunately those events are also fired when you leave a site over a link or your browsers back button.

***You can only detect when the page is unloaded, not when the window is closed. Also, the `onbeforeunload` is non-standard, so it's not supported by all browsers.***

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for

window.close();

Comment: `window.close()` only closes windows that were opened by a script (and in Chrome, the middle mouse button too, apparently). If that's the case with this question, then yeah, `window.close()` will do it.

Comment: alt+F4 use for close current entire window